# Programmatically adding UILabel is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to practice here, I have a `SearchBar` in my view and i've used

```
  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
```

Once the user starts writing, I hide on of my views, and make another one programmatically

Here's my concept, Once i start writing, my 2nd view comes in:
[image: Gif]

But once i get the second view properly added, i'd like to add a UILabel to it. Here's my code:

```
    self.word_of_the_day_view.isHidden = true // main view

    self.popularView.frame = CGRect(x: self.searcy_bar_view.frame.minX, y: self.searcy_bar_view.frame.maxY + 15, width: self.searcy_bar_view.frame.width, height: self.searcy_bar_view.frame.height) // don't mind the height and width


    self.popularView.backgroundColor = .white
    self.popularView.layer.cornerRadius = self.searcy_bar_view.layer.cornerRadius
    self.popularView.popIn() // just an animation
    is_popular_added = true

    self.view.addSubview(popularView)

    let label_1 = UILabel()
    label_1.frame = CGRect(x: self.popularView.frame.minX + 3, y: self.popularView.frame.minY, width: self.popularView.frame.width, height: 20)
    label_1.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-regular", size: 13)
    label_1.text = "Hello World!"
    label_1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    popularView.addSubview(label_1)
```

But on runtime, the UILabel isn't even added.

[image]

Thank you so much for even reading the question!

Comment: Have you tried running the [view hierarchy debugger](https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6) to see where the label is placed? Also, I strongly recommend using autolayout constraints instead of manually setting the size of your views.

Comment: `label_1.frame = CGRect(x: self.popularView.frame.minX + 3, y: self.popularView.frame.minY,...` Shouldn't this be `label_1.frame = CGRect(x: self.popularView.bounds.x + 3, y: self.popularView.bounds.y,...`?

Comment: @Larme, If you think that my way isn't correct. Please make it an answer,

Comment: @Palle, I haven't done that, Plus i did constraints a few times they messed up my UI

Comment: I don't use `minX`, `minY`, so I'm not sure that it isn't doing already that. But since  `label_1` will be a subview of `popularView`, it means that it will be "relative" to it. In other words, in the coordinates of `label_1`, {0,0} will be to top left of `popularView`, not the screen or any other view.

Comment: @Larme. So this has to do with minX and minY

Comment: No. The issue is about `frame` vs `bounds`. And you should use `bounds.origin.x` and `bounds.origin.y`, or directly use 0 since there value should be 0.

Comment: @KimberlyLife I strongly recommend learning to use autolayout constraints to ensure that your UI works on different screen sizes and orientations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between Frame and Bounds.
The Frame of the view is the position of the view in it's super view, so his origin can have any value of a CGPoint.
The Bounds are just the view itself, so it always have an origin of (0,0)

I think the problem is

```
label_1.frame = CGRect(x: self.popularView.frame.minX + 3, y: self.popularView.frame.minY, width: self.popularView.frame.width, height: 20)
```

try to change in

```
label_1.frame = CGRect(x: self.popularView.bounds.minX + 3, y: self.popularView.bounds.minY, width: self.popularView.frame.width, height: 20)
```

or

```
label_1.frame = CGRect(x: 3, y: 0, width: self.popularView.frame.width, height: 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
label_1.frame = CGRect(x: self.popularView.frame.minX + 3, y: self.popularView.frame.minY, width: self.popularView.frame.width, height: 20)
```

This is because `self.popularView.frame.minX` and `self.popularView.frame.minY` have some  +value that crosses the boundary of the current view on which you are trying to add `label_1`.
you should use `self.popularView.bounds.origin.x and self.popularView.bounds.origin.y`

**Difference between bounds and frame**

**frame** = a view's location and size with respect to the parent view's coordinate system

**bounds** = a view's size using its own coordinate system

Answer (score 0):

This issues is due to confusion between frames and bounds. I also got similar issue in on of my app.

The **bounds** of an `UIView` is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system (0,0).

The **frame** of an `UIView` is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to the superview it is contained within.

you should use `self.popularView.bounds.origin.x` and `self.popularView.bounds.origin.y` in place of `self.popularView.frame.minX` and `self.popularView.frame.minY`